# Почему одежда из хлопка называется хлопчатобумажной?

Tags: этимология

Почему одежда из хлопка называется хлопчатобумажной?
При чем здесь бумага?

Upd:
В [Национальном Корпусе Русского Языка](http://www.ruscorpora.ru/search-main.html) фраза [бумажный платок](http://search-beta.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%E1%F3%EC%E0%E6%ED%FB%E9%20%EF%EB%E0%F2%EE%EA&p=1) со значением «платок из ткани» упоминается 18 раз. Последнее использование — не позднее 1930 года в С. В. Обручев. «В неизведанные края. Путешествия на Север 1917-1930 г.г.» 1954 года издания.
Начиная с примерно 1940 года используется слово *хлопчатобумажный*.

Но тут возникает новый вопрос.
Цитата из О. М. Сомов. «Сватовство» (1831):

> На голове у ней был шелковый платок, подвязанный наколкой, как у городских мещанок; на ногах голубые шерстяные чулки и башмаки без задников, с высокими каблуками; прочий наряд ее составляли шушун и юбка *ситцевые* с большими разводами ярких цветов да клетчатый *бумажный* платок на шее.

Из чего тогда делался ситец и чем ситцевая ткань отличалась от бумажной?

Comment: Собственно само слово "бумага" происходит от "хлопка" (bombacium), а не наоборот. Хорошую бумагу и сейчас делают из хлопка (деньги, например ;-)

Comment: То есть вместо _хлопчатобумажный_ можно было сказать _бумажный_?

Comment: Бумажная ткань, бомбазин, бумазея. С той оговоркой, что тогда качество "бумазеи" было намного ниже современной ХБ.

Comment: I only want to add to the previous answer, that the worlds "бавовна in Ukrainian, бавоўна in Belarusian, bawełna in Polish" are obviously connected not with Latin/Italian/Russian "bombacium/bambagia/бумага" but with the German word "Baumwolle" ('cotton').

Comment: @Alexey `German word "Baumwolle"` - Baum stands for "tree" AFAIR, and wolle... worm?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Хлопковый`/`хлопчатый` and `хлопчатобумажный` indeed mean the same thing. As for why the second form is used instead of the first one, which is both more intuitive and shorter - here's a [quote](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9#.D0.A5) from Wikipedia:

> В русской технической литературе до второй половины XIX века вместо
>   слова «хлопок» применяли термин «хлопчатая бумага», сохранившийся до
>   настоящего времени в словах: хлопчатобумажная ткань, хлопчатобумажная
>   промышленность и других.

So, your assumption is wrong – it has not started in Soviet times. This word indeed is used in books starting from XIX century. Actually one can trace even to earlier times. Here's a [quote](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0) from document dated 1745:

> Здесь же при Астрахани, хотя по опытам довольно видно, что делание
>   шелка и сеяние бумаги хлопчатой немалую приносить может пользу.

As for `ситец`, in the same article you can find that it is a "лёгкая хлопчато-бумажная гладкокрашеная или набивная ткань, получаемая в результате специальной отделки сурового миткаля". So, it is a sort of fiber made of cotton, one of many. Just like миткаль, бумазея, бязь, вельвет and others.

And one final note. Just like @Matt correctly noted, most probably "бумага" is derived from Italian word (derived in turn from a Latin one) which stood for cotton. It is very likely but no one knows for sure actually. Also, in other Slavic languages, even in the closest to Russian `бумага` is not used for paper at all, but for cotton we have:

- бавовна in Ukrainian
- бавоўна in Belarusian
- bawełna in Polish
- bombaž in Slovenian.

It is very disputable how exactly these forms find their way into the languages mentioned above, we can end up finding ourselves in the land of stupid pseudo-linguistic assumptions. Most probably these words are related but definitely not always directly with `бумага`.

Comment: `Хлопковый/хлопчатый and хлопчатобумажный indeed mean the same thing` - when applied to the "made of" context. However a cotton field would not be хлопчатобумажное поле :-D